# Having trouble with reading a csv file

Tags: python, csv, python-requests

I'm new to Python,and I don't have much experience with the libraries.
I'm trying to get a CSV file from 'www.bankofcanada.com' using the "requests" module for my Currency converter program.I want to read the file,and parse it in order to get the currency and it's ratio, for using them in a dictionary.
The 2 parts,individually work just fine (I can get the CSV file and save it,and I can parse the CSV file as I want when there's already a file).My problem is they dont work together and giving me empty results:(

```
import requests
import csv
import os
import time

rates = {


        }

os.chdir('C:\\Users\\Caroline\\Desktop')
res = requests.get("http://www.bankofcanada.ca/en/markets/csv/exchange_eng.csv")
csvFile = open('csvFile2.csv','wb')
for chunk in res.iter_content(10000):
    csvFile.write(chunk)
fh = open('csvFile2.csv')
fileReader = csv.reader(fh)
fileData = list(fileReader)
actual_data = fileData[7:]
for rows in actual_data:
    rates[rows[0]] = rows[-1]


print(rates)
```

**P.s:** I know there are lots of improvements to the code like not using absolute paths and ... 
This is just for debuggin purpose

Comment: What do you mean by "empty results"? Your code created a non-empty csv file for me. Are you sure you are checking the file under the right directory?

Comment: Why do expect a file you downloaded by the name of `exchange_eng.csv` will open just file with the filename `csvFile2.csv`?

Comment: @ayhan
it should go something like this : {'Jamaican dollar': ' 0.01092', 'Colombian peso': ' 0.000418', ...}
but when Im printing rates,it's an empty dictionary

Comment: @ThomasR.Koll
I'm not sure what do you mean? I'm creating a file with that name..

Comment: oh sorry, I overlooked the "wb".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not closing your file after writing it so there is nothing there to read. You need to do this for all file operations*. Use the the `with open` form to have Python handle this automatically:

```
with open('csvFile2.csv','wb') as csvfile:
    for chunk in res.iter_content(10000):
        csvFile.write(chunk)
with open('csvFile2.csv') as fh:
    fileReader = csv.reader(fh)
```

Here's the equivalent code closing the file handlers manually:

```
csvFile = open('csvFile2.csv','wb')
for chunk in res.iter_content(10000):
    csvFile.write(chunk)
csvFile.close()
fh = open('csvFile2.csv')
fileReader = csv.reader(fh)
fh.close()
```

As you can see it's longer with close. The with open format is also safer as its easy to forget to close the filehandler if you are doing it manually.

Python has lots of nice language features designed to make life easier as a developer, that don't necessarily have a direct equivalent in other languages. It is worth getting to know them. People talk about 'Idomatic Python' (as a good thing) and one of the things they mean by this is using these built-in shortcuts rather than rolling your own.

*Files need to be open *and* closed so they can be written (and read) safely. As a user the closing is always handled for us so its easy to think only in terms of opening a file, but as programmers we dealing with a lower level operation. When you write to a file nothing actually gets written to it until you close the file, even though it appears you are writing a line at a time in a loop. This helps prevent file contents getting clobbered by other processes among other things.

Comment: Your diagnosis is correct, but the problem would be clearer if you first give equivalent code using `close()`.

Comment: Thanks...that actually worked.
can you explain a bit more why this is happening?
and why I had to put fh.close() after fileData = list(fileReader) ?

Comment: @Caroline.M it's good practice is to use a context handler (`with` statement) to manage the closing of the file automatically when exiting the `with` block. Generally make exception handling behave correctly when dealing with these resources.

Comment: @AChampion
thanks for the tip.
so,Behind the scene,what will happen if you forget to close a file?

Comment: @Caroline.M it depends on your application. Data may not get written (flushed) out to the file until it is closed, you may run out of file descriptors. All these things get cleared up when the application ends, so it becomes very important for server applications.